# Importing a f2py .pyd from an explicit path (Bad magic number ImportError)

Tags: python, f2py

I have built a .pyd module from some fortran code via `f2py`, which we can call `foo.pyd`.  I want to import this into a python code, which we can call `main.py`.  When I import as:

```
import foo
```

everything works fine.  However, because this python will eventually be 'frozen' into an executable, and I will have to package the `foo.pyd` along with the `main.exe`, I need to specify an *explicit* path to import from.

Thus, I tried using the `imp` module, specifically `imp.load_compiled()`.  When I try:

```
import imp
foo = imp.load_compiled('foo','foo.pyd')
```

or even:

```
foo = imp.load_compiled('foo','./foo.pyd')
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: Bad magic number in foo.pyd
```

It seems that this error comes from trying to build in one Python dist, and import in another.  However, I'm using the same Python for both, **and it works with the standard `import` command!**

Has anyone out there experienced this, and/or possibly have some guidance?  I greatly appreciate any help or advice you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imp.load_compiled()` is for `.pyc` files.  You're looking for `imp.load_dynamic()`.  Alternatively, you can add the directory you want in `sys.path`, after which regular imports will work.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I wanted to avoid altering the path of the destination machines, so `imp.load_dynamic()` is perfect!